# How to access to the processes in Android 7.0 or above Nougat?

Tags: android, process, android-7.0-nougat

I tried to access the process information through the '/ proc' file. But it didn't work. I wonder to know how Greenify implement this function. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can no longer do this in Android 7.0. With Android 7.0, Google has significantly restricted access to /proc.

This limitation/feature has already been reported to Google:
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=205565

An alternative would be to use UsageStatsManager.

Comment: UsageStatsManager need to require user access permission... Anyway, Thank you!